# HDMI to DVI-I adapter no signal without vga

Tags: linux, hdmi, dvi, ubuntu-12.04, hdcp

I bought a computer monitor (MAG 22" LED H2201L-NS 1920X1080 2MS + DVI-D), and I have a laptop that only has a vga connection and an HDMI connection. bearing in mind that I want to connect it to my laptop through the HDMI port and since I had already an HDMI cable which I used for my PS3, I bought an HDMI to DVI-I adapter (the only one in store).

The problem is that it doesn't get detected by my laptop through the HDMI cable (no signal). So, what am I missing here? Is it a problem with the adapter? Should I bring an HDMI to DVI-D adapter... (This is not the issue, I guess, since the analog signal will be discarded by the monitor, and it will read only the digital one).

And also I haven't tried it on my PS3 yet but will it work ... or will it have the same PC problem (my PS3 died on me so I sent it to get fixed. YLOD problem)?

(Here is the new issue that I discovered. It is that the HDMI port only shows it is connected, and I can use it when the vga port is connected to the same monitor. Why? The same happens on both Windows and Ubuntu, but when I remove the vga cable keeping the HDMI port connected, it says HDMI1 disconnected using the xrandr.

Comment: Does the manual of the MAG 22 specify if it needs a dual link DVI connection? (I would have looked it up myself, but http://www.maginnovision.com/ seems unreachable.)

Comment: no it doesn't. it says that the DVI port is DVI-D .... but what I found  at the store is an HDMI to DVI-I adapter...

Comment: I have to note that it is HDCP compliant

Comment: I will bet on bad cable/adapter, do you have an option to test the screen with the VGA connection to the laptop? Can you also check the DVI cable with another computer with DVI output?

Comment: yeah it works fine on a vga cable but I only have my laptop so I can't test the other part of your suggestion.

Comment: will I have tested and since I am using linux ubuntu I have noticed that it shows hdmi and vga as two monitors but when I disconnect the vga it also disconnects the HDMI .... wierd...??? nevermind